# Process huge no of records

Tags: records

I have developed a web application using spring mvc framework. My concern is I need to display huge no of records say around 100,000.

What would be the best approach to display those many no of records in UI.

Comment: You need to post somethings that you have done for the community to help. I would advise pagination..?

Comment: What exactly is your issue??

Comment: I am trying to loop through the records(1,00,000) and display it in the form of table, there the browser is getting crashed.

Comment: IE is taking huge amount of time and is getting crashed,
Though Chrome takes time but generating the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a front end framework like `AngularJS` get the data in `JSON` format and access the `JSON` data through your Angular code and use pagination. I have worked on a similar app and a fronted framework solved the problem.